# SQL Joining journal tables to user tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a `MSSQL` database with 3 tables: `Journals`, `Customers`, and `UserAccounts`.

I'm trying to query `Journals` for transactions per account manager. This table has a `customer ID` column that links to `Customers`.

The `Customers` table has a `ACC_Manager` column that links to `UserAccounts` via `UserID`.

Inside the `UserAcounts` table are `first` and `last` name columns.

So it would be

```
Select
    Journal.amount,
    Customer.name,
    UserAccounts.first
From
    Tables
where
    Journal.ACC_manager = 'Matt'
```

I'm having issues joining the tables so I can query using `UserAccounts.first`. Could anybody help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I didn't get exact column names so don't just use this code without modifying it a bit to suit your specific needs:

```
SELECT
    j.amount,
    c.name,
    u.first
FROM
    Journals j
    JOIN Customers c ON
        c.customerID = j.customerID -- Exact column names?
    JOIN UserAccounts u ON
        u.UserID = c.ACC_Manager
WHERE
    u.first = 'Matt'
```

You may also need to use `LEFT JOIN` as opposed to `JOIN`. Read up on JOINs to be sure.